Change order of codecs that ffmpeg will attempt
TBH this might be a bug since I cannot see why this would be designed behavior:
I'm converting user-submitted videos to png thumbnails with this command.
ffmpeg $codec -xerror -ss 1 -t 0.05 -i "$1" -update 1 -frames:v 1 -vf "scale=-1:256" -y "thumb.png"

This works great when there is no transparency involved, but when it is I get PNGs with black (or green, whatever the non-transparent component is) background. I need to manually select the input codec for VP8 (alpha_mode=1), VP9, and fallback (seems to use vp8 (native)) like this to fix it
for codec in "-vcodec libvpx-vp9" "-vcodec libvpx" ""; do

Now my questions are

is there a way to just set my preference order of codecs as a command line option?
WHY is FFMPEG failing to use the best codec in the first place?


get codec_name
#!/bin/bash
f="videos/webm with alpha channel 1.webm"
#f="videos/webm with alpha channel 2.webm"
vid=$(ffprobe -v error "$f" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1)
echo $vid
if [ "$vid" = "vp8" ]; then
  vid="libvpx"
else
  vid="libvpx-vp9"
fi
ffmpeg -c:v $vid -ss 0.6 -i "$f" -frames 1 -vf "scale=-1:256" /tmp/out.png -y -v error -stats
xdg-open /tmp/out.png


Technically that doesn't answer my question, but this might be the smartest thing to do. We definitely a improvement over my current solution!
